# Refresh Window in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, refresh

I've a Visual C++ project but I don't be able to refresh the window and redraw itself.
I've used

```
RedrawWindow();
m_ProgressDlg->RedrawWindow();
```

and also

```
UpdateData(false);
m_ProgressDlg->UpdateData(false);
```

but never seems go well.

How can I do?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [UpdateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167%28VS.85%29.aspx) in conjunction with [InvalidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get an immediate redraw.

Answer (score 2):

For client area use InvalidateRect + UpdateWindow.
If you want to redraw the non-client area of the window, try calling SetWindowPos with SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE.

Comment: Absolute life saver. Actually more like sanity saver. Been looking a long time for a solution like this. thanks.

Comment: `UpdateWindow` does not return until WM_PAINT is processed by PROC.

Comment: Painting (drawing) of the window frame without calling OnSize is what is was looking for. Wanted this for debugging and design purposes. It is not going to be in the final code, but is good for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

::InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE) WinAPI function (or wnd->InvalidateRect(NULL) method) should do the trick: it invalidates client area and causes the system to send WM_PAINT to the window to redraw it. If you want immediate redraw, you should also call UpdateWindow() just after invalidation.

Comment: InvalidateRect doesn't work immediately, it just causes a WM_PAINT message to get generated eventually. Other messages have priority, so it may be a while before the window repaints. This is usually what you want though - the app shouldn't become unresponsive just because it's constantly repainting itself.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks for a notice - "immediate" left from the previous post version. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using MFC.

I believe your app is busy and not processing messages from the queue, so it's not processing the WM_PAINT that would update the window.

Use the RDW_UPDATENOW parameter with RedrawWindow to force the repaint, even when your window is busy.

Answer (score 0):

But in release version it doesn't function correctly also if with openeed worspace it seem to go

Comment: It's not clear which answer you're responding to. Put your responses into the original question as Edits.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be trying to call Invalidate() and RedrawWindow() while m_hWnd is NULL, if by "not going well" means crashing. Try:

```
if (m_hWnd)
{
   Invalidate();
   RedrawWindow();
}
```

(I know this is old, but some of us still have one foot stuck in the MFC muck.)